# Finding last case with square brackets?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is probably extremely simple.

Using `dplyr` and `group_by(users)`, if I use something like `filter(Date[1] == "01-14-15")` within the group it will find users that have their first date as 01-14-15.

How do I set it so it will find the user's last date instead of their first date?

`filter(Date[1] == "01-14-15")`: find users with first case of date

`filter(Date[?] == "01-14-15")`: find users with last case of date?

Comment: Can you show me a piece of data? like head().

Comment: replace`?` with`nrow(dt)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need to `filter` the last row per group that also is the same as a particular Date, then, we can use

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df1, Users) %>% 
       filter(row_number()==n() & Date=='2012-01-03')
```

Or if you need to get all the rows of a group whose last 'Date' is the same as a particular Date, then

```
group_by(df1, Users) %>% 
               filter(Date[n()]=='2012-01-01')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Users=sample(LETTERS[1:4], 20, replace=TRUE),
 Date= sample(seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), length.out=4, by='1 day'), 
          20, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Or `group_by(df1, Users) %>% 
  filter(Date=='2012-01-03') %>%
  tail(1)`

Comment: @SamFirke Thanks for the comments, I guess that will be for the first option I mentioned.   But, I am not sure it will work as `tail(1)` gets the last observation

Comment: @SamFirke Suppose, if I change `df1$Date[20] <- '2012-01-03'`, this would only give a single row

Comment: Good catch.  A better implementation of my approach for your first option is `group_by(df1, Users) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  filter(Date=='2012-01-03')`